# eager php newb requesting advice on wordpress code

Tags: php, wordpress

### Designer just starting out with PHP looking for a more elegant solution

I'm trying to a create a div that only appears beside posts if they have comments. The only 
code I can get to work is below & that's by creating two variables I feel a more experienced person than myself wouldn't need, I just can't express what I'm looking for with code. This is my first week working with php so I've been googling for solutions & can only find examples of generating the number of comments with the wordpress function get_comments_number(); & then hiding the divs that have 0 with javascript which seems overly complicated for something so trivial.

I like to have something more like the bottom piece of code especially the way it outputs the singular & plural comments text after but I'm not competent enough yet.

Any examples / advice would be greatly appreciated

```
       <?php 
          $b = 0;
          $commBox = get_comments_number();

          if($commBox <=$b) {
                echo ""; 
          }else{
                echo "<div class=\"commentbox\"> $commBox </div>"; 
        }?>
```

---

```
     <?php if ( have_comments() ); ?>
     <div class="commentbox">
     <?php printf( _n( '1 comment;', '%1$s comments;', get_comments_number(), 'ves'),
     number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) ); ?>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the following code. This would only create a div if the post did have comments, meaning you wouldn't need any JavaScript to hide ones without, as they wouldn't exist:

```
<?php 

if ( get_comments_number() > 0 ) {

echo '<div class="commentbox">';

comments_number( 'no comments', 'one comment', '% comments' );

echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

Notice the use of the `comments_number()` function which is good for what you wanted to do in regards to showing different values based on single or multiple comments. The function reference can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/comments_number).

Comment: Thanks for replying, Anything i've tried apart from the very first piece of code either outputs an empty div or a div with 0 comments.

Comment: Ive edit the answer above, try this instead and let me know

Comment: A pleasure @Chrmur. I've updated it with an easier version of the `printf()` function using WordPress own built in `comments_number()` function which may be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks again Jim & Peter for sharing your knowledge & experience

Comment: +1 Nice use of the inbuilt wordpress function.

Answer (score 1):

A clean up to the top code (which I think is what you're asking for would be:

```
   <?php 
      $commBox = get_comments_number();
      if($commBox) {
            echo "<div class=\"commentbox\"> $commBox </div>"; 
    }
    ?>
```

This just basically checks that $commBox is true (in PHP 0 is false, non zero numbers are true) and removes the uneccessary `echo ""`.

You could create a have_comments() function just by having a function that returns get_comments_number() but I'm not sure that's necessary.

Edit: Something like:

```
echo "<div class=\"commentbox\"> $commBox comment" . ($commBox == 1 ? 's' : '') . " </div>";
```

Should show "comments" if there are more than 1 comment and "comment" if there is one comment (though this is untested).

Comment: Thanks Jim that works perfectly I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer. Any advice on how i could incorporate the singular & plural strings after the output number?

Comment: @Chrmur No problem, glad I could help. I've updated my answer to deal with plural/singular. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again Jim & Peter for sharing your knowledge & experience.

Comment: Hi @Chrmur, thats why we're here! I've given Jim an upvote for his answer on your behalf as I know you said you couldn't

Comment: @Peter Thanks I've been trying to do this for a couple of hours & i just couldn't figure it out. I'd have came to stack far sooner if i'd have known I'd get such friendly & helpful advice.